# Using Sirv Api class with codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I'm trying to use Sirv Api with my codeigniter project. This is the error I am getting

> Message: Too few arguments to function SirvAPIClient::__construct(), 0
> passed in 'xxxx' and at least 2 expected

this is my code

```
$sirv = new SirvAPIClient(
    'CLIENT_ID',
    'SECRET_ID',
    'client id here',
    'secret key here',
    'Sirv PHP client'
);
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Sirv API client for PHP](https://sirv.com/help/articles/sirv-rest-api-php/), the syntax should be like this:

```
$sirv = new SirvAPIClient(
    'client_id_here',
    'secret_key_here',
);
```

For example, your code will look something like this:

```
$sirv = new SirvAPIClient(
        'Y0jrOfiwnr7dpEWIdFiIhg0Keo8',
        'NJ7Jq7ZioVxyQ92hJgLX7Hc43QTTj1A2KywiDJsLycaDbqmGpC6lc04LOiDqC4RHE3392AMiQ=='
);
```

Before you can connect, first you must have called the PHP API client library:

```
require_once('application/libraries/SirvAPIClient.php');
```